# Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site when called method Stop() throws NotImplemenetedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, notimplementedexception, web-administration

I am trying to stop a website in IIS.

Here is my code

```
Site oSite = SERVERMANAGER.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.IndexOf(websiteName) > -1);
if (oSite != null)
{
    //stop the site...
    oSite.Stop();
}
```

When it reachers oSite.Stop(); it will throw

> "The method or operation is not implemented."

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium and the version of IIS I'm using is 7.5.

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Your code works fine on my 2012 R2 when the application pool runs as `local system`. I don't have any Windows 7 anymore. Also review your lambda expression, it may not find your site (case sensitive) or may find another one (there may be another site with a similar name). Why not check for equality?

Comment: i'm using indexof is because i identify the unique name using some parts of the full name. I'm running on my local. i tried to run application pool as local system but still it doesn't work. Probably is cause of IIS version. Will try on my server tomorrow. Thanks man.

Answer (score -2):

Your method may be seems like this

public void Stop()
{

throw new NotImplementedException();

}

remove above line from your method and write method code

Comment: So you are saying Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site, method Stop provided by Microsoft is just throwing exception? then there is no other way to fixing it?